# Media keys on Macbook Pro and i3

Tags: 16.04, brightness, i3-wm, media-buttons

I have just configured Ubuntu on my MacBook Pro (June '15), and I have put i3 on it. I am mostly glad with the result, but I cannot figure out how to configure my

- Media keys (play, pause)
- Volume keys
- Keyboard brightness keys.

They all work perfectly when using Unity - but not in i3. For some reason my next/previous keys work, and so does the screen brightness keys. I tried to follow the following guide:
https://faq.i3wm.org/question/3747/enabling-multimedia-keys.1.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I now see that the following text in my i3 config file makes the media keys and the screen brightness work.

## Pulse Audio controls

```
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +2%; exec pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ 0
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ -2%; exec pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ 0
bindsym XF86AudioMute exec pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ toggle
```

## Media player controls

```
bindsym XF86AudioPlay exec playerctl play-pause
bindsym XF86AudioNext exec playerctl next
bindsym XF86AudioPrev exec playerctl previous
```

## Sreen brightness controls

```
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessUp exec xbacklight -inc 20 # increase screen brightness
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessDown exec xbacklight -dec 20 # decrease screen brightness
```